# C# : Socket.Send error

Tags: c#, sockets, buffer, byte

I'm having a weird problem with a C# program. A server send me a calculation in Polish prefix notation, and i must return the result. The problem is that even if the result is good, the server send me that it's a bad answer. And i don't understand why. For exemple (result is just after the '#' line):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5LxX.png

For this calculation i saved the buffer that my program sent to the server :

```
54
57
52
50
55
50
52
54
52
54
10
```

So it's all good for the buffer...

Here is the code which send the result:

```
sbuffer = new byte[result.Length + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
     sbuffer[i] = Convert.ToByte(result[i]);
}
sbuffer[result.Length] = Convert.ToByte('\n');
s.Send(sbuffer);
```

If someone understand from where this problem come...
Thank you for help and have a nice day! :)

Comment: The expected result and the one you sent are obviously the same. So, there must be a flaw in the way you deliver it. Here, I don't know what the server expects. A byte-array, ok. But `\n`-terminated? And possibly, the bytes need to represent the `int`-value, not the `char`-value, like this: `sbuffer[i] = (byte)Convert.ToInt16(result[i])`?

Comment: When i connect to the server with netcat, it send me the calculation and then i have to enter the result and press enter, that's why i put a '\n' at the end of my byte-array. Btw i tried to use the int value as you said but it was unsuccessful. TY anyway! :)

Comment: When you find out what exactly netcat sends, you're done.